# Rails - How to use active record to query with a nested condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

lets say I have three Models

```
User(id, guest(boolean))
 belongs_to :room_user
Room (id)
RoomUser (id, room_id, user_id)
 has_many :users
```

Right now I can do, room.room_users and get back all the associated users that are in that room. That's very doable with rails.

What I want to do now is something like Room.room_users_active

So in the Room model I have:

```
def room_users_active
   self.room_users.where(:......)
end
```

The challenge here is I want the condition to reach into the user table. And do the following:

Return all the room_users where the user is not a guest (User.guest == false).

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but it should work, try and let me know

```
def room_users_active
   room_users.joins(:users).where('user.guest = false')
end
```

Fixed a wrong method call see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Comment: Thanks, that errors with wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)

Comment: That's just about it, couple of typos worth updating. . thank you! ---- joins(:user).where('users.guest = false')

Comment: @AnApprentice Does it work with `joins(:user)`? I remember that you should use the plural form (i.e. `joins(:users)`) because it's a many associations, maybe I'm wrong...